# json result in element

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Hello I have the following code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "bot.json",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET"
}).done(function (data) {
    $('#jsummary').html(data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

I want to display the response in the #jsummary div but it is just empty. What am I missing. The json in bot.json is valid.

Comment: use the success callback rather than the .done promise

Comment: well you can also use `success` callback.

Comment: What kind of data does the console log?

Comment: @Newcoma You cannot directly see the json output in cosole log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is a javascript object.

If you want to view it as text, you need to serialize it :

```
$('#jsummary').html(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this

```
$('#jsummary').html(JSON.parse(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "bot.json",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#jsummary').html(data);
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: @DipeshParmar My bad, fixed